# Dynamically generating a list of targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If a file exists, I want to add a target to build. If the file does not exist, I want the target to be skipped.

an example:

```
FILENAME = f

TARGETS := normal
ifneq($(shell stat test_$(FILENAME).c), "")
  TARGETS += test
endif

all: $(TARGETS)

normal: 
    @echo normal

test: 
    @echo test
```

I'm not sure the `$(shell stat ...)` part even works, but the bigger problem is that `make` with any file `test_f.c` in the current folder gives:

```
Makefile:4: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

Removing the `ifneq ... endif` block makes the target `normal`. How can I only run the target `test` if `test_f.c` exists?

Comment: You forgot the space after `ifneq`. It should be `ifneq ($(shell stat test_$(FILENAME).c),)` (the quotes are literally matched).

Comment: @AndreaBiondo Oh, wow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is generate a string variable (let's call it `OPTIONAL`) such that when 'test_f.c' exists, `OPTIONAL=test`; otherwise, `OPTIONAL=_nothing_`. And then add `OPTIONAL` as a prerequisite of `all`. e.g.:

```
FILENAME = f

TARGETS = normal
OPTIONAL = $(if $(wildcard test_f.c), test, )
all: $(TARGETS) $(OPTIONAL)

normal: 
    @echo normal

test: 
    @echo test
```

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, do you know what is wrong with the syntax of the Makefile in the question? Is it just that one target expands to two?

Comment: Sorry I can't see why this problem happens to you since I can't reproduce the same problem on my machine. But the error message is usually caused by multiple colons on the same line. You may want to check for rogue colons in your makefiles. A wild thought: the result returned by `stat` happens to contain strings like "...Sep 23 16:52:12...". The colons in this string may somehow pollute your makefile (even though I can't see exactly how right now)

Comment: To help you debug, you can add this line `.%:; @echo $*=$($*)` to your makefile, and then use `make .TARGET` or whatever variable name to check the value of `TARGET`. If you can see a colon in `TARGET`, that would be the problem.

Comment: @MingjingZhang He's just missing a space after `ifneq`. The only place where colons cause issues is in target names and prerequisites.

Comment: @Andrea Biondo Thank you very much for pointing that out. Somehow I didn't notice that missing space.

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate over targets with for loop

```
.PHONY: all

RECIPES = one

all:    RECIPES += $(if $(wildcard test_f.c), two, )
all:
        for RECIPE in ${RECIPES} ; do \
                $(MAKE) $${RECIPE} ; \
        done
one:
        $(warning "One")

two:
        $(warning "Two")
```

---

```
> make
for RECIPE in one   ; do \
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make ${RECIPE} ; \
    done
makefile:11: "One"
make[1]: `one' is up to date.

> touch test_f.c

> make
for RECIPE in one  two ; do \
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make ${RECIPE} ; \
    done
makefile:11: "One"
make[1]: `one' is up to date.
makefile:14: "Two"
make[1]: `two' is up to date.
```

Comment: Please, wherever possible, prefer to use dependencies rather than shell loops in makefiles. That will make your build parallel safe, and you won't need recursive make. Your loop also has an issue where you are ignoring _make_'s return code.